# How to check a query in CodeIgniter 3.0.3 (delete,update,select,insert)?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a project in codeigniter 2.0 and I used:

```
$query = $this->db->query('select * FROM my_table');

if($query->num_rows()==1) return true; else return false;
```

But in codeigniter 3.0.3 i don't know how to check (update, select, insert, delete... ).

Comment: Read [manuall](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data)

Comment: check my updated ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Cogidignitor User Guide 3:

**For Select:**

The number of rows returned by the query. Note: In this example, $query is the variable that the query result object is assigned to:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table');
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

**For UPDATE & INSERT Statements:**

```
$this->db->affected_rows()
```

> Displays the number of affected rows, when doing “write” type queries
>   (insert, update, etc.).

**Example:**

```
$this->db->update('UPDATE statement');
$this->db->affected_rows();

$this->db->insert('INSERT statement');
$this->db->affected_rows();
```

**Alternate for INSERT:**

You can also use last insert id as like:

```
$this->db->insert('INSERT statement');
$id = $this->db->insert_id();

if($id > 0){
  return true;
}
else{
 return false; 
}
```

**For Delete:**

DELETE always return the true in result if query executed else false, affected_rows will also return same:

```
$this->db->delete('DELETE statement');

if($this->db->affected_rows()){
  return true;
}
else{
  return false;
}
```

Comment: please leave some comments downvoter... will help to improve

Answer (score 1):

**for insert,update**

> `$this->db->affected_rows();`  Displays the number of affected rows, when

doing “write” type queries (insert, update, etc.).

```
if ( $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ) 
   {
   return TRUE;
   }
   else 
  {
   return FALSE;
   }
```

**for select**

doing “select” type queries (insert, update, etc.).

```
 if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
       $dataSet = $query->result();
    }
```

**for delete**

```
$res = $this->a_model->delete_product($id); // example delete 

if($res == FALSE)
{
}else
{
}
```

Comment: Will an update or delete always provide an `affected_rows()` result of 1?  If so, there must be a bug there as multiple rows can be updated or deleted by a query, and you'd want the `affected_rows()` result to reflect that

Comment: @gabe3886 affected_rows() return how many rows are updated or inserted.... i have update my answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM my_table");
$dataSet = array();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   $dataSet = $query->result();
}

print_r($dataSet);
```